# REST PUT does not seem to connect to the server

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, rest

**[SOLVED]**

[Subir Kumar Sao](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1193808/subir-kumar-sao) was completely right, it was a CORS issue and not client side, in case someone else gets to the same problem by hosting a server coded with C# this would be the solution:

Get the assemblies from [CORS support for ASP.NET Web API](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=CORS%20support%20for%20ASP.NET%20Web%20API) and reference them to your server project, and under your `HttpSelfHostConfiguration` you insert the following which would in the end look like this:

```
var config = new HttpSelfHostConfiguration ("http://10.0.5.106:8000");

var enableCorsAttribute = new EnableCorsAttribute ("*", "*", "*")
{
    SupportsCredentials = true
};
config.EnableCors (enableCorsAttribute);
```

---

**[Question]**

I'm running a server I wrote under *C#* with *VS2013* for a LED-Light control application hosted in a canvas using *KineticJS*.

I tested it out using the *Postman* extension for *Chrome* and it worked flawlessly, I could GET and I also could PUT.

since it is my first time coding something using REST I decided to go with `.ajax` from *jQuery* which seems very well documented. But for some odd reason it won't work and I'm quite in a loss since maybe I'm missing something, and I neither can check what is going on since the ex returned from "error" is empty.

Here is the code I'm using for the client side:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://10.0.5.106:8000/api/LED/Save',
    type: 'PUT',
    data: { N: '1', Pos: '10' },
    success: function() { alert('PUT completed'); },
    error: function(req,status,ex){alert(ex);}
});
```

To understand the structure of my server, here is the code of it aswell:

```
private static void RestServer()
{
    var config = new HttpSelfHostConfiguration ("http://10.0.5.106:8000");

    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes ();
    HttpSelfHostServer server = new HttpSelfHostServer (config);
    server.OpenAsync ().Wait ();
    while (true) {
    }
}

[RoutePrefix ("api/LED")]
public class LEDController : ApiController
{
    [Route ("Save")]
    public HttpResponseMessage PutSave(int N, int Pos)
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse (HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
    }

    [Route ("Load")]
    public HttpResponseMessage PutLoad(int N, int Pos)
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse (HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
    }
    [Route ("Intense")]
    public HttpResponseMessage PutInt(int N, int I)
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse (HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
    }
    [Route ("RGB")]
    public HttpResponseMessage PutRGB(int N, int R, int G, int B, int I)
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse (HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems a CORS issue. Does page calling the ajax service reside in the same domain `10.0.5.106`?.

Comment: Yes, everything resides in the same domain, the Client App resides in a diferent PORT though, if this matters at all.

Comment: Try passing the parameter like this, `data: "N=1&Pos=10",`

Comment: Unfortunately that was the first way I passed the parameters, doesn't work aswell, changed to what I have now to make the structuring easier in the long run.

Comment: @Subir Kumar Sao you were 100% correct, it was a CORS issue, I had to enable it server side using [System.Web.Http.Cors](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=CORS%20support%20for%20ASP.NET%20Web%20API), should I'll update my answer with the solution, if you want you can copy paste it and I'll mark it as an answer since you were right to begin with.

Comment: I was facing the same issue. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a CORS issue.

Read more [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/).

And read [here](http://enable-cors.org/) on how to enable CORS.